# How to convert sql nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, date, converters, datediff

How can i convert a nvarchar column that contains yyyymm in a date format (for example 201208 to 20120801). I will need to do after this a datediff.

Thanks

Comment: Which database? and you want to fix the date part as 01 always?

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the example you have given, you only want to add 01 at last in your date, so you can use String concatenation to get the target result.

Example:

```
SELECT 'dateis' + space(3) + date1 + '01' AS moddate1
FROM users
```

You can check the code:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3177c/2

I am not sure whether it will solve your problem completely but you can use this code.

Thanks